# How to hide the code of firefox extension

Tags: firefox, dll, xul, toolbar

I made an IE toolbar by BHO with C#. And now I want to make a firefox version.
I planned to use xul but it will show the source code to the user. 
Seems DLL is not a good way in firefox.

I tried some toolbar like yahoo, google which will not create files in extension folder.
How can I make something like that?

Answer (score 1):

*(please see my note about obfuscation below)*

It might not be the optimal way to develop a Firefox extension, but you can absolutely build them using an external DLL.

Before Gecko 2.0 you had to use the rather esoteric Mozilla build toolchain to include compiled code in your extensions.

js-ctypes to the rescue:

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/js-ctypes/js-ctypes_reference
```

js-ctypes makes very easy work of loading external DLLs and binding their APIs to JavaScript functions.

You'll need to compile a few different versions of your DLL, and have your JavaScript correctly detect the platform and load the appropriate DLL, but it basically works the same for all platforms once you're back in JavaScript land.

`ctypes.libraryName` helps you determine the extension the DLL has on the current platform (e.g: .dll for windows, .so for Unix).

You can use other information (e.g: navigator.userAgent) to more concretely determine which sub-platform (e.g: Windows 7 64bit, or Vista 32bit).

---

**Update:**

There are a whole bunch of good reasons to included compiled DLLs in your extensions/applications (e.g: speed, special capabilities, 3rd party libraries), but if your sole purpose is obfuscation (hiding source code), then...

I wouldn't worry about it were I you. Technological means of anti-piracy won't get you very far in this modern world - if your software is good enough to get attention, someone *will* crack it.

I'd simply forget about  it, and spend a little money on lawyers instead. (Copyright: yay! Patents: nay!)